# Card View Button Adaptor

Tags: android-layout, android-studio, android-cardview

I created a blank Activity and having this main layout:activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.solution.engineering.lecture_time.MainActivity">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/note">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:text="@string/welcome"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/description"
                android:text="@string/description"
                android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_below="@+id/title"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/note">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="@string/button_text"
                android:id="@+id/button_lecture">


            </Button>

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

And my MainActivity.java file looks like:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button lecture;
    public void setnew(){
        lecture=(Button)findViewById(R.id.lecture_button);
        lecture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent create = new Intent(MainActivity.this,LectureActivity.class);
                startActivity(create);

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setnew();
    }
}
```

I need to launch a new Activity from the button-click,this code shows no error but while running it on my device it won't launching the LectureActivity.
What could be the possible changes in my java file to implement the onclick.
If that has anything to do with adaptor for cardview,then how do i define the adaptor class.
I am new to android programming. Appreciate any kind of help.Thanks.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErzgK.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question. Don't know why this ain't working but, instead of this`startActivity(create)` I changed it to `MainActivity.this.startActivity(create);` and it worked.